# How to make main view component aware of changes happening to app component variable?

Tags: angular, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, parameter-passing

When there is no connection between app component and main view component, I need to make the main view component aware of the changes happening to app component variable. Below are the files

index.html

```
<head></head>
    <body>
        <custom-componenet id="custom-component" username="enduser"></custom-component>
        <aside>
            <script>
                function onUserChange(value) {
                  document.body.querySelector('custom-component')
                    .setAttribute('username', value);
                }
          </script>
          <label>
            Username:
            <select onchange="onUserChange(this.value)">
              <option value="enduser" selected>EndUser</option>
              <option value="tester">Tester</option>
            </select>
          </label>
        </aside>
    </body>
```

app.component.html

```
<svg>
        // some symbol tag declarations
    </svg>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app.component.ts

```
export const WEB_COMPONENT_SELECTOR = 'custom-component';

    @Component({
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom,
      changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnChanges, OnInit {
        @Input() username?: string;

        ngOnInit(): void { }

        ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    
        if (changes.username) {
          console.log('user changed to ', changes.username.currentValue);
        }
      }
    }
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: '',
        component: MainViewComponent
      }
    ];

    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
        anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
        onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload',
        useHash: true
      })],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: OverlayContainer,
          useClass: OverlayContainerService
        }
      ],
    })
    export class AppModule implements DoBootstrap {
      constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

      ngDoBootstrap() {
        if (!customElements.get(WEB_COMPONENT_SELECTOR)) {
          customElements.define(WEB_COMPONENT_SELECTOR, createCustomElement(AppComponent, { injector: this.injector }));
        }
      }
    }
```

overlay-container.service.ts

```
@Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class OverlayContainerService extends OverlayContainer {

      protected _createContainer(): void {
        const containerClass = 'cdk-overlay-container';
        const container = this._document.createElement('div');
        container.classList.add(containerClass);

        this._document.querySelector(WEB_COMPONENT_SELECTOR)?.shadowRoot?.appendChild(container);
        this._containerElement = container;
      }

    }
```

main-view.component.ts

```
@Component({
      selector: 'clh-main-view',
      templateUrl: './main-view.component.html',
      encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated,
      changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
    })
    export class MainViewComponent implements OnInit {

        constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

        ngOnInit(): void {

        }

    }
```

main-view-routing.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forChild([
        {
          path: '',
          component: MainViewComponent
        }
      ])],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class MainViewRoutingModule {}
```

main-view.component.html

```
<h2>Welcome {{username}}!!!</h2>
```

I need to use the variable **username** from index.html/app.component.ts which gets updated from the drop-down, in main-view.component.html. Could anyone suggest a better way of doing this?

Comment: the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-using-a-service) it's related to comunicate througth a service two components that are not parent/child relationship (Yes, the title is confussed). You can also google for comunicate two components using a service.